# How do I map several elements to a single class in JAXB

Tags: java, mapping, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have following XML on input:

```
<root>
 <response1></response1>
</root>
```

or

```
<root>
 <response2></response2>
</root>
```

And there is possibly a lot of response tags each of which I need to map to a single Response class because they have almost the same structure.

Is it easy to do in JAXB?

Thanks.

Comment: Avoiding the issue somewhat ... will simply changing the XML string work? E.g. changing `response1`, `response2`, `responseN` to `response` and just map that instead?

Comment: Hi @Paul, I like to avoid the things, but in this case we have the response predefined from the web-service which is not under our control :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done with the `@XmlElements` annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="response1", type=Response.class),
        @XmlElement(name="response2", type=Response.class),
        @XmlElement(name="response3", type=Response.class)
    })
    private Response response;

}
```

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

Comment: +1 Fancy, I've never tried to play around with the JAXB annotations; usually I just tweak the XSD file and let xjc do the rest. :-P

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young - Here is a link to an article that demonstrates how to generate this annotation when starting from an XML schema:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, sure. In XSD file, define a type first:

```
<xs:complexType name="response">
  <!-- define type here -->
</xs:complexType>
```

Now define your elements using it:

```
<xs:element name="response1" type="response"/>
<xs:element name="response2" type="response"/>
<!-- and so on and so forth -->
```

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for answer. Is it possible to specify substitution groups with annotation?

Comment: No, as far as I know there is no annotation for that. In any case, for what you want to do, substitution groups seemed to be a red herring (I think I misread your question initially).

Comment: @Vladimir - You can use the `@XmlElements` annotation to specify substitution groups:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392076/how-do-i-map-several-elements-to-a-single-class-in-jaxb/7392935#7392935

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work this way. It uses an [XMLStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) as the source, and a [StreamReaderDelegate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate.html) to intercept and rewrite the element names before they reach jaxb.

The main test class:

```
package grimbo.test.jaxb;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;

public class JaxbTest {
    public static <T> T unmarshal(Class<T> clazz, InputStream inputStream) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException,
            FactoryConfigurationError {
        XMLStreamReader r = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        MyXMLStreamReader my = new MyXMLStreamReader(r);
        String packageName = clazz.getPackage().getName();
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(packageName);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        return (T) u.unmarshal(my);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml1 = "<root>" + "<response1>test1</response1>" + "</root>";
        String xml2 = "<root>" + "<response2>test2</response2>" + "</root>";

        Object ob = unmarshal(Response.class, new ByteArrayInputStream(xml1.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(ob);

        ob = unmarshal(Response.class, new ByteArrayInputStream(xml2.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(ob);
    }

    static class MyXMLStreamReader extends StreamReaderDelegate {
        public MyXMLStreamReader(XMLStreamReader reader) {
            super(reader);
        }

        public QName getName() {
            QName qname = super.getName();
            return qname;
        }

        public String getLocalName() {
            String localName = super.getLocalName();
            if (localName.matches("response\\d+")) {
                return "response";
            }
            return localName;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Response` class is:

```
package grimbo.test.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root", namespace = "")
public class Response {
    String response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response [response=" + response + "]";
    }
}
```

And there's a jaxb.index file in this package too, that declares the Response class:

`Response`

The output of the test is:

```
Response [response=test1]
Response [response=test2]
```

Is this any help?

Comment: Thanks for brainstorm. I was looking to something more declarative like @XmlElements.

Comment: No problem. The chosen answer is certainly best for a limited set of known tags. I'm interested if it could cope with more complex matching than simply listing the tag names?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do imo would be to make the response element an unbounded list in your schema then once you have created your bindings you can iterate throught the list of response nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to map multiple tag to single class using JAXB with same format mention above.
    
      
    
    Now define your elements using it:

```
<xs:element name="response1" type="response"/>
<xs:element name="response2" type="response"/>
<!-- and so on and so forth -->

While unmarshalling JAXB validates the XML(format) with response class  format mentioned in XSD file ,but its is giving me JAXB.element class object instead of response object.

Please suugest with answer..
```